# How to set SHELL variable in makefiles generated by CMake?

Tags: cmake

CMake creates Makefiles that contains:

```
# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh
```

How can I change this value of SHELL that will be written in all makefiles?

Comment: Why do you want to change this?  If you hard code some other path then your build environment might not be portable anymore.

Comment: Because in my environment (Ubuntu customized by my company) /bin/sh is forced to link to /bin/bash (just like in the old days...) and I'd like to use /bin/dash instead, I believe it could slightly improve compilation time.

Comment: Did you try `SHELL=/bin/dash make`?

Comment: It doesn't work. In fact I've just seen in cmake source code that /bin/sh is hard-coded!... See Source/cmLocalUnixMakefileGenerator3.cxx file. Which means there is no solution. Except maybe a request for change...

Comment: On some systems it is done so that `/bin/sh` points to `/bin/bash`, so technically you may override it to whatever you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in my last comment, /bin/sh is hard-coded in Cmake (Source/cmLocalUnixMakefileGenerator3.cxx), so there is no way to change it...